# What Database/ Datastructure to use for discrete 2D (landscape) map of values?

Tags: database

I hope this is not a too stupid question to ask. Grateful for any advice.

I want to store a 2d landscape consisting of discrete values in a database.
The value for each point represents what type of landscape it is (20 = tree).
Not each point must be defined/ stored.

[image]

I expect ~ 10.000 read- operations per minute, the write operations are neglectible (<1 per minute). 
A optimal query might look like: "Return all values around point (x/y) with radius r." or "Return all values in a given rectangle."

I wont host the hardware by myself and will rent the server/ cloud sulution that is needed. In case it makes any difference: Prefered language for BE and FE is JS, but Java, Scala and C# are viable options, too.

1. What kind of database and datastructure would you use for this use case?
2. What if clients should be able to subscribe to changes in certain areas - how would you tacle this problem in theory?
3. What if each point holds a JSON, not an integer?

Comment: Too broad of a question. What do you consider "many" operations, how much data will be stored in the database, on what hardware will it be running, what language will you be using to operate on it if any, etc.

Comment: Hello Alexander, thank you! I will update the question immediately.

Comment: Does it have to be a grid?  You may be better off with something with GIS capabilities.  PostGIS for postgres lets you do Geospatial queries usually used for cartography but lets you do rasterizing on data in spatial coordinates so you can gather data for locations.  Beyond that you may be able to partition areas into different clusters of databases so that they can optimize reads.  You have to decide what's best for you

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond PostGIS looks really good. This might be it. :) Thank you very much, I'll try it out right away!

Comment: What about the data? How many records do you expect to be stored in the database? How many records do you expect to fetch per query. At 10k/minute or 167 queries per second you should consider the amounts of IO required to make it sustainable. MySQL or postgres could work for your task given the right configuration and hardware But I would advise you to consider some caching if possible(redis is by far my favourite option given things like lists, increments, pub-sub patterns, etc).